# Trigger successfully compiled but not firing

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm making a database that supports the original version of "Settlers of Catan", and while most of it works as intended, this trigger does not.

I'm working on Oracle 18c through SQL Developer, alongside Netbeans for a related Java application (this will be of discussion in another question).

These are the tables that are involved:

```
CREATE TABLE giocatore(
    numero INT,
    colore VARCHAR2(20),
    punto_partenza INT,
    punti_vittoria INT DEFAULT 0,
    vittorioso CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f',
    quant_clay INT,
    quant_wool INT,
    quant_wheat INT,
    quant_wood INT,
    quant_rock INT,
    CONSTRAINT player_pk PRIMARY KEY(numero)
    );
```

```
CREATE TABLE esagono(
    numero INT,
    tipo VARCHAR2(30),
    terreno VARCHAR2(10),
    punti_vittoria INT,
    gettone INT,
    matprod VARCHAR2(20),
    quant_mat INT,
    occupato_da INT,
    occupato_in_turno INT,
    CONSTRAINT hexa_pk PRIMARY KEY(numero),
    CONSTRAINT ocp_fk FOREIGN KEY(occupato_in_turno) REFERENCES turno (numero_turno),
    CONSTRAINT mat_fk FOREIGN KEY(matprod) REFERENCES materia_prima (tipo),
    CONSTRAINT occ_fk FOREIGN KEY(occupato_da) REFERENCES giocatore (numero)
    );
```

```
CREATE TABLE materia_prima(
    tipo VARCHAR2(20),
    quantita INT,
    CONSTRAINT type_pk PRIMARY KEY(tipo)
    );
```

```
CREATE TABLE turno(
    numero_turno INT,
    val_dadi INT,
    CONSTRAINT turn_pk PRIMARY KEY(numero_turno)
    );
```

And here is the trigger itself:

```
create or replace TRIGGER generate_prime
AFTER INSERT ON turno
DECLARE valextracted INT; produced esagono.matprod%TYPE; quantity INT; occupied esagono.occupato_da%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT val_dadi
    INTO valextracted
    FROM turno
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ORDER BY numero_turno DESC;
    FOR record IN (SELECT matprod, quant_mat, occupato_da INTO produced, quantity, occupied FROM esagono WHERE gettone = valextracted)
    LOOP
        UPDATE materia_prima
        SET quantita = quantita + quantity
        WHERE tipo = produced;
        IF produced = 'Argilla' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_clay = quant_clay + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Grano' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wheat = quant_wheat + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Lana' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wool = quant_wool + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Legno' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wood = quant_wood + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Minerali' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_rock = quant_rock + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I expect the trigger to update GIOCATORE's quant_clay/wool/wheat/wood/rock rows and MATERIA_PRIMA's quantita row according to ESAGONO's quant_mat but that does not happen. Any ideas?

Comment: The first query in the trigger which fetches the value of `valextracted` seems incorrect. Can you please explain what logic you think you have implemented in that query?

Comment: It does not seem to me that anything is wrong with the first select I just want to know what value do you get there into a valextracted  and then what do you get with the loop select ? Start of a DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec4b187662af80e48d328f6858109bfc

Comment: My logic in the first query is that I want to get the most recently extracted value from the thrown dice. In "Settlers of Catan" each hexagon in the playing field has a token, and when the extracted value from the thrown dice matches that of a hexagon's token, said hexagon produces a set amount of prime materials. However, there can be multiple hexagons in the playing field that share the same token value.

Comment: Hi @NicholasMarsicano. Check the answer I have posted. Hope that will help.

Comment: Did you intend for this to be a statement trigger, as it is, instead of a row trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have founded your problem. 
You should replace this part:

```
FOR record IN (SELECT matprod
                  , quant_mat
                  , occupato_da 
           INTO produced
                , quantity
                , occupied 
           FROM esagono 
           WHERE gettone = valextracted)
LOOP
```

With this:

```
    FOR record IN (SELECT matprod
                          , quant_mat
                          , occupato_da 
                   FROM esagono 
                   WHERE gettone = valextracted)
    LOOP
        produced := record.matprod;
        quantity := record.quant_mat;
        occupied := record.occupato_da;
```

Here is the trigger that works:

```
create or replace TRIGGER generate_prime
AFTER INSERT ON turno
DECLARE 
   valextracted INT; 
   produced esagono.matprod%TYPE; 
   quantity INT; 
   occupied esagono.occupato_da%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT val_dadi
    INTO valextracted
    FROM turno
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ORDER BY numero_turno DESC;

    FOR record IN (SELECT matprod
                          , quant_mat
                          , occupato_da 
                   FROM esagono 
                   WHERE gettone = valextracted)
    LOOP
        produced := record.matprod;
        quantity := record.quant_mat;
        occupied := record.occupato_da;

        UPDATE materia_prima
        SET quantita = quantita + quantity
        WHERE tipo = produced;

        IF produced = 'Argilla' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_clay = quant_clay + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Grano' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wheat = quant_wheat + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Lana' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wool = quant_wool + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Legno' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_wood = quant_wood + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        ELSIF produced = 'Minerali' THEN
            UPDATE giocatore
            SET quant_rock = quant_rock + quantity
            WHERE numero = occupied;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I legitimately thought about this solution but never even believed it would actually work. Thank you!